# Where can I see the suggested edit review policy?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I'm trying to understand what does "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer" mean exactly, to know why my rejected edit was inappropriate, and to avoid future problems, I'd like to see the rules in full. I can't seem to find that in the Help Center.

Comment: Related → [How suggested edits work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: Related → [Guidelines for Reviewing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

Answer (score 1):

[What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing), that is the answer I was looking for.